# Update a counter cache column after restoring a record with paranoia (acts_as_paranoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, counter-cache, acts-as-paranoid

I have a `counter_cache` column in my model. I use `acts_as_paranoid` for this model ([Paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)). How to update a counter cache column for an associated record when I restore a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `before_restore` callback. Place [`.increment_counter` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) for an associated record inside this `before_restore` callback.

[`reset_counters` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_counters) or `+= 1` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a model concern solution to this problem.

You should already have the paranoid gem installed if you are facing this problem but for completeness-sake, include the paranoid gem in your Gemfile and install it using the 'bundle' command.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'paranoid'
```

Create a concern.

```
# app/models/concerns/paranoid_deletable.rb
module ParanoidDeletable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # activate the paranoid behavior
    acts_as_paranoid
    # before restoring the record, manually increment the counter
    before_restore :increment_counter_cache
  end

    module ClassMethods

      def counter_column_name
        "#{self.name.underscore.pluralize}_count"
      end

    end

    def counter_associations
        associated_counters = []
        # get all belongs_to associations
        self.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).collect do |association|
          return unless association.options[:counter_cache]
          associated_klass_name = association.options[:polymorphic] ? self.send("#{association.name}_type") : association.class_name
          associated_klass_name.constantize.column_names.each do |column_name|
            # collect the association names and their classes if a counter cache column exists for this (self) class.
            associated_counters << { association_name: association.name, klass_name: associated_klass_name } if(column_name == self.class.counter_column_name)
          end
        end
        # return the array of { association_name, association_klass } hashes
        associated_counters
      end

    private

    def increment_counter_cache
      # before restore...
      self.counter_associations.each do |counter_association|
        association_name = counter_association[:association_name]
        klass_name = counter_association[:klass_name]
        # ...increment all associated counters 
        klass_name.constantize.increment_counter(self.class.counter_column_name.to_sym, self.send("#{association_name}_id".to_sym))
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in your model.

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ParanoidDeletable
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  ...
end
```

A few setup notes:

1) your pluralized belongs_to :association_name must match your counter cache column name: "#{association_name}_count". For example:

```
# Will work
console > user.posts_count
          => 212
# Won't work
console > user.how_much_they_talk_count
          => 212
```

2a) If you are using a polymorphic relationship, it's associations need to be set up appropriately in both models. For example:

```
# app/models/post.rb
....
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
....

# app/models/comment.rb
...
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
...
```

2b) If you are using a polymorphic relationship, the reference type field needs to be named as follows: "#{association_name}_type". For example:

```
# Will work
console > comment.commentable_type
          => "Post"
# Won't work
console > comment.commentable_class_name
          => "Post"
```

Disclaimer: I tried to make this modular but it's a first-pass and I haven't tested it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple solution, though some will disagree with the semantics.

```
module ActiveRecord
  # trigger create callbacks for counter_culture when restoring
  class Base
    class << self
      def acts_as_paranoid_with_counter_culture
        acts_as_paranoid
        simulate_create = lambda do |model|
          model.run_callbacks(:create)
          model.run_callbacks(:commit)
        end
        after_restore(&simulate_create)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you just have to replace your invocations of `acts_as_paranoid` with `acts_as_paranoid_with_counter_culture`.